# Reboot few seconds later after program termination

Tags: c++, c, linux, shell

I am maintaining a c/c++ program under linux, which will change BIOS settings and reboot to enable new settings.

Now test teams need to verify exit status, but the program will reboot right now after termination, so their script doesn't have enough time to record the status.

I have try `system("shutdown -r -t 1")`, but it will wait for 1 minute.I just need few seconds delay time but `shutdown` has no option for it.

Are there other methods( besides **at** or **cron**) to implement a few seconds reboot delay time after program termination?

Comment: `man shutdown` says that the `-t` value is in seconds, not minutes (?)

Comment: @Emilien Yes, you are right! It is true in RHEL.  It's a pity that Ubuntu/FreeBSD has no this option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try next line:

```
system("nohup  bash -c 'sleep 10; shutdown -r -t now' > /tmp/shutdown.log&");
```

This with return inmedialty your program and after 10 seconds will invoke the sutdown